# Can 理由 mean "logic" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, words, nuances, manga

In a manga, the characters are trying to find out the culprit of some homicides. One of the character is basically saying that if they keep thinking in a logical way, they will never find out who the culprit is. Then he says this:

> だって　この物語には…　最初からまともな理由なんてなかったんだから。

Could 理由 be interpreted as "logic" in the sentence above (and in general)? Translating it as "reason" or "motive" doesn't fit the context in my opinion, because they knew since the beginning that the culprit was a 殺人鬼 and there wasn't a motive for the homicides. My translation attempt:

> It's because this story has never followed any logic.

Later on they will discover that they had made the wrong assumption that another character was killed, while he actually faked his death instead. [Here you can see the two pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZZsz.jpg) where it is taken from for more context. Thank you for your help!

Comment: 「（殺人の・事件の）動機・理由」"motive, reason" って意味でいいのでは・・・　「そもそもこの殺人/事件には、動機・理由はなかった。(There was no motive or reason, to begin with.)・・・　なのに、僕たちは意味・動機・理由があると勘違いして、推理しようとした。。それは間違いだったんだ。」って感じで。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that the characters are having difficulty with or are confused with the case at hand.  They just can not get how the culprit could kill without a motive without a reason, it is not normal and the same situation, in reality, would cause real detectives just as much difficulty as the characters in the manga.

The translation is reason or motive, if the characters are detectives "motive".  If just regular people "reason".